# How can I allow a user to upload multiple text files, then save them to a string and display them (in PHP)?

Tags: php, file

I want to allow a user to upload multiple text files using a simple HTML form, and then save them to a string. After that, I want to display them to the user. For example, say I have three text files with the following contents:

file1.txt: this is some text.

file2.txt: this is some more text.

file3.txt: even more text!

When the user uploads them using an HTML form, I want to save them to a string and display them like so:

this is some text.

this is some more text.

even more text!

I have the following (incomplete) code that attempts to get only one file:

```
    Upload text documents: <br /><br>
    <form action="output.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="file" size="50" />
    <br />
    <input type="submit" value="Upload File" />
    </form>

    <?php
    $doc = $_POST['file'];
    echo $doc;
    ?>
```

How can I loop through the files and save them to a string, then display them in the best way possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$filenames = array();

    if(isset($_FILES["documents"]))
    {
       for($i=0; $_FILES['documents']['name'][$i] != '' ; $i++)
       {
           $filenames[$i] = $_FILES['documents']['name'][$i];

           $myfile = fopen("$_FILES['documents']['name'][$i]", "r") or die("Unable to open file!");

           echo fread($myfile,filesize("$_FILES['documents']['name'][$i]"));

           fclose($myfile);

        }

    }
```

I think this is helps for you!!!!!!!1

Answer (score 2):

In completion of White Marcus answer

> use the multiple="multiple"attribute in the input file element.

You should have : $_FILES variable, instead of $_POST

```
<?php

  var_dump($_FILES);

?>
```

To print a file use [file_put_contents()](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.file-put-contents.php)

Best regards

Comment: Thanks but how can I save the contents of the files to a string?

Comment: Edit answer : use file_put_contents function

Answer (score 1):

```
    $filenames = array();

    if(isset($_FILES["documents"]))
    {
       for($i=0; $_FILES['documents']['name'][$i] != '' ; $i++)
       {
           $filenames[$i] = $_FILES['documents']['name'][$i];
        }

    print_r($filename);
    }
```

Comment: I tnk , Are u got it?

Comment: Would this print only the file name? I want to save the contents in each of the uploaded files to a string. @White Marcus

Answer (score 0):

use the `multiple="multiple"`attribute in the input file element.

Comment: <input type="submit" value="Upload File" multiple="multiple"/> exactly this.

Comment: Ok say I did that. How do I loop through the files and save them to a string? @White Marcus

Comment: add another attribute name. <input name="documents[]" type="submit" value="Upload File" multiple="multiple"/> use this name attribute's documents array u can easily fetch the file names and store it into string using implode() method.

Comment: Thanks for that. Can you show me how to store the file contents into a string by giving me the code for it? @White Marcus